# What is the probability that the committee will be made up of equal numbers of men and women?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have the following exercise of multiple option:

> You have four men and five women to make a committee of four people. If the committee is constituted by taking random people, what is the probability that the committee will be made up of equal numbers of men and women? 
>  a)$\frac{1}{5}$  b) $\frac{1}{2}$   c) $\frac{4}{9}$  d)$\frac{20}{21}$

My solution:
There's $\binom{9}{4}$ ways to select committee, i.e., there's 126 ways to select committee.  Now, selecting equal number of man and women in group of 4 implies 2 men and 2 women so

selecting 2 men of 4 is $\binom{4}{2}=6$

selecting 2 women of 5 is $\binom{5}{2}=10$

so $P(A)= \frac{6 \cdot 10}{126}=\frac{60}{126} = \frac{10}{21}$

but this is not an option ... I don't understand if I am making a mistake. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Your solution is correct.

Comment: Welcome indeed.  It is refreshing to see a new user post a well structured question like this.  Thank you for showing your work and your thoughts on the problem.  Again, yes your solution is correct.  I encourage you to use more thoughtful titles in the future that apply to your specific problem only and are not merely generic descriptors which apply to millions of other problems as well.  Also, consider taking the time to [learn some mathjax and $\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) as it can help with readability.

Comment: Thank u for your answers and for mathjax tip. I know some $\LaTeX$ but didn't know how to use it here. I'll use it from now. Thanks again.

Comment: Since your answer is correct I'm guessing that's what option d) was supposed to have been, but was mangled by a typo.

Comment: Hmm... you are correct.  Either its a typo or maybe its an error in that the author thought you had calculate choosing the men first and then the women, and choosing the women first then the men.  That's wrong though, of course.  You could do there are $9\cdot ... 6$ was to choose a committee (with order) and there are $({4\choose 2}\times (4\cdot 3))({2\choose 2}\times (5\times 4)$ ways to make positions for the men and and fill them and the positions for the women and fill them, but becomes $\frac {10}{21}$.

Answer (score 1):

Oscar, your solution is correct. The alternatives provided in the original question don't include the right answer either due to a typo or a mistake. It is not uncommon. BTW, congratulations for your first question.